# Declaring An Instance Of A Class With Member Initializers In Another Class

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11

So I have a class whose contructor contains member initializers like so:

```
class aClass
{

public:

//Functions
aClass(int sVal1, float sVal2, float sVal3,float sVal4);        //Constructor
~aClass();                                                       //Destructor

private:

int someValue;
float sSomeValue;
float tSomeValue;
float fSomeValue;
};
```

The constructor looking like this in the .cpp file of the class:

```
NPC::NPC(int sVal1, float sVal2, float sVal3, float sVal4)
:someValue(sVal1), sSomeValue(sVal2), tSomeValue(sVal3), fSomeVlaue(sVal4)
{

}
```

My question is: if I were to declare an instance of this class in another class header file as a private variable, what would the syntax of declaration be?

Comment: Here is a simplified example: http://ideone.com/OVvorn

Comment: Yes that example is fine if the implementation and interface file of the other class are one and the same but if the interface file ie. the header file is seperate from the implementation, how do you declare an instance of the aClass in the interface file of the other class - do you have to call the constructor in the interface file or can you simply declare an instance of the aClass like a variable - without initializers?

Comment: I don't understand. You just declare the variable, but it must be included in the initialization list of the constructor or you will get a compiler error: http://ideone.com/2oTKgh

Answer (score 1):

In the other class' header you'd have something like:

```
class anotherClass {
public: 
    anotherClass(); 
    anotherClass(int sVal1, float sVal4);
    ...
private: 
    aClass mya; 
};
```

Of course, as you use there `aClass`, you need to include the header of your first class as well.

In your cpp you'd then initialize things like this:

```
anotherClass::anotherClass()
     : mya(0,0,0,0) {}  // as aClass has no default constructor, 
                        // you must always make sure the init list provides for mya 
anotherClass::anotherClass(int sVal1, float sVal4) 
     : mya(sVal1, 0, 0, sVal4) {}
```

Remark:  as `aClass` has no default constructor, you must make sure that you inialise it in `anotherClass` initialisation list.